# Schedule a .js file to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, automation, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to find a solution of how to execute a JavaScript file a couple of times a day (Like Task Scheduler on Windows)
At the moment, I execute the file in VS Code or Command Prompt using node file.js.
Is there any way to automatically execute it?
I have tried the following with Task Scheduler, but is not executing the file, just opening VS Code:

Action: Start a program
Program/script: "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
Arguments: -l -i -c "C:\Users\desktop\folder_containing_the_file; node writeToFile.js"

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. Obviously nothing can happen while the computer is turned off, so what would you want to happen when it is turned on again? Would it need to run the task as many times as it should have run if the computer had never been turned off?

Comment: Thank you, I misread that can do it if it is connected to power, but it has to be turned on. Thank you for clarifying.
I want to be able to run the file at least once a day, but to set it to be done automatically. I can leave the computer on when I m on holiday for example, and get the file executed without me remotely connecting to the computer and execute it manually.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be executed when the computer is off. But you could use the [Amazon AWS Free-Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/en/free) services to schedule and run it.

Comment: I understand that now, thank you. I thought I can do it if the computer is turned off.
How can I automatically execute it when the computer is on then? With Task Scheduler, Actions, I added the path of VS Code in Program/script, then for Actions : -l -i -c "node C:\Users\my_name\onedrive\desktop\folder_name\writeToFile.js" It is opening the JavaScript file, but not executing it.